# How to enable flash on winRT Arm in specific site with stream?

Tags: flash, stream, windows-runtime

How to enable flash on winRT Arm in specific site with stream like Putlocker or Nowvideo ?

I know that flash is embedded in internet explorer 10 for ARM and in some site work, how activate the other site or force to use flash?

Thanks,
Chida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. It's intentionally locked down.

[Here](http://liliputing.com/2012/11/windows-8windows-rt-browser-hack-use-flash-on-any-website.html) is a bit more detail.